# If "If $A$, then $B$ and not $C$" is true, then is "If $A$ and $C$, then not $B$" true?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Suppose "If $A$, then $B$ and not $C$" is true. Is the following statement true?

If $A$ and $C$, then not $B$.

I know the answer is true but I don't know the basis behind it.

Comment: Do you know how to use truth tables?

Answer (score 2):

$X \implies Y$ is true if $X$ is false **or** $X$ and $Y$ are true.

Thus, if $A$ is false, the first statement is true. Also the second statement is true if $A$ is false for the same reason.

On the other hand if $A$ is true, then $C$ has to be false (and $B$ has to be true but that does not matter) in the first statement.
But if $C$ is false the second statement is true!

---

Hoewever, you could also do a truth table to prove this assumption
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&A\implies(B\wedge\lnot C) & (A\wedge C)\implies\lnot B\\
\hline
0&0&0&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}\\
0&0&1&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}\\
0&1&0&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}\\
0&1&1&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}\\
\hline
1&0&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&0&1\\
1&1&0&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}\\
1&1&1&0&0\\
\end{array}$$

We can see here that both statements are **not equivalent** but everytime the first statement is true, the second statement is true as well

Answer (score 1):

You can forget about B entirely. Since A implies $\lnot$C, the compound statement "A and C" is false. Since the hypothesis of your second conditional is false, the conditional statement as a whole is true no matter what you write as the conclusion.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but how do you know that A and C is false from A implies not C?

Comment: @user127340 A is either true or false. If it is false, then A$\wedge$C is false. If it is true, then it implies C is false, which in turn implies A$\wedge$C is false.